# Mocking a WCF-service on different environments

Tags: c#, wcf, deployment, mocking, visual-studio-2015

In my application I'm using a WCF-Service.
This service is not available on all my environments.
On my local pc and on our DEV-environment we need to mock the WCF.

But when I deploy my application to ACCEPT, I need it to connect to the real WCF and not the mock.

What is the best way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have multiple environments, I prefer to use different environments in Visual Studio as well. You already have Debug and Release Environments. But you can also setup this to fit your needs.
For example: Release Prod, Release QA, Debug.
This way, each environment can have its own config file for a different publish profile.

So you can specify in your config which service type should be used in which environment

or

you can also use compiler directives in code:

```
#if DEBUG
    service = new WcfServiceMock();
#else
    service = new WcfService();
#endif
```

Comment: I use the first approach.